# Error "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command" when the command is not there in the code

Tags: automation, salesforce, command-line-interface, sh, devops

So, I've been trying to automate the whole cloning repo, authorizing org, scratch org creation and metadata deployment process. I had earlier generated a SSL certificate and added that as a connected app in my devub org and got the Consumer key below.

However, I am getting this error after Step 5(which is just authorizing my devhub org)
I am getting this error:
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

But what's strange is I don't even have this command 'C:\Program' anywhere in my code.(pasting below)

```
printf "STEP1: SET End/Temp Variables\n"
export CONSUMER_KEY=3MVG9fe4g9fhX0E5XMgzYs83zQJC2K_avOF.Izh19SWsfOHVYLW28jU.uzXIcCjqY1zUeEzaVLEYx321Kuj1mv
export DEV_HUB_USER_NAME=droy@sfdcfacts.com 
export SERVER_KEY_LOCATION="/C/VS Projects/assets"
export SFDC_PROJECT_LOCATION="/C/VS Projects"

printf "STEP2: Move to project directory\n"
cd "$SFDC_PROJECT_LOCATION"

printf "STEP3: Make Project directory of name $(date +'%Y%m%d')\n"
mkdir $(date +'%y%m%d')
cd $(date +'%y%m%d')

printf "STEP4: Clone Github repo\n"
git clone https://github.com/choudharymanish8585/tree-plantation.git
cd tree-plantation

printf "STEP5: Authorise devhub org\n"
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid=$CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile="$SERVER_KEY_LOCATION" --username=$DEV_HUB_USER_NAME --setdefaultdevhubusername -s --setalias=CLIAutoDevHub

printf "STEP6: Create scratch org\n"
sfdx force:org:create -s --setalias=$(date +'%y%m%d') --wait 10 --durationdays=30 -f config/project-scratch-def.json

printf "STEP7: Push metadata to scratch org\n"
sfdx force:source:push

printf "STEP8: Assign perm set to user\n"
sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n TreePlantation

printf "STEP9: Upload sample data to scratch org\n"
sfdx force:data:tree:import -p sample-data/import-plan.json

printf "STEP10: Opening scratch org\n"
sfdx force:org:open
```

The transaction outcome is like this:

```
STEP1: SET End/Temp Variables
STEP2: Move to project directory
STEP3: Make Project directory of name 20211007
STEP4: Clone Github repo
Cloning into 'tree-plantation'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 147, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 147 (delta 0), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 144 eceiving object
Rec 77% (114/147)
Receiving objects: 100% (147/147), 1.33 MiB | 2.86 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (38/38), done.
STEP5: Authorise devhub org
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
STEP6: Create scratch org
ERROR running force:org:create:  This command requires a dev hub org username se
t either with a flag or by default in the config.
```

and ofcourse the steps after this gave error as well...

Anyone can please help me with this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that somewhere in your code is written:

```
C:\Program Files
```

The issue is that whichever thing you're using decided to cutoff the string after the space ' ' symbol.

You can try solving that by adding quotation marks " as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files"
```

Comment: Tried searching through several times. C:\Program Files is not used anywhere I can even think of in the code (pasted the whole code above). I am even using bash CLI navigations so I'm sure I never used powershell navigation commands here

Comment: I have the same thing, and it happens when trying to retrieve/deploy with sfdx.